# What keeps switching on my proxy settings?

Tags: windows-7, internet, proxy

It's happened to me a two or three times in the past year that suddenly my browser is unable to open any web site.  Because it hasn't happened all that often, it usually takes me about 20 minutes to eliminate any kind of internet outage as a cause, at which point I notice that my browser is failing to connect to a proxy server.  I then open my internet settings and uncheck "use a proxy server" checkbox, which I never set in the first place!

I am the only user on my computer.  I am forced to the conclusion that some program running on my computer is unilaterally deciding that I should be using a proxy server - but what?  Are there any common culprits for this?  Any idea how to track this annoying behavior down?

Comment: Is the user a domain or local user?  Go ahead and remove the masked profanity.

Comment: @Ramhound, local user

Comment: Scanned for malware yet? If you really want to try and track it, get ProcMon from MS.

Comment: @techie007, I do believe the other question matches mine, plus I'm also using Visual Studio (though a later version), so immediately that looks like a hit!  Thank you!